# Bypass Thunderbird to open Gmail directly

Tags: software-recommendation, gmail

On Ubuntu 16.04, how can I bypass Thunderbird to open Gmail directly? I don't know how to place Gmail icon on my Launcher or Panel. When reading a Gmail message in Thunderbird, I can't see the "Add to calendar" button. I don't want to replace Thunderbird as the default mail application, but I want to have an additional option when desired. I'm fairly new to any computer use, and am not familiar with much terminology.

Comment: The question is unclear. What do you want to achieve? Thunderbird can work with Gmail if you set up an account. What do you mean by "open Gmail directly"? Open the web site?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it looks to me like he wants to "bypass Thunderbird to open Gmail directly" in a different app.

Answer (score 6):

There are seven Gmail integration apps in the default Ubuntu 16.04 repositories.

1. **Gmail** (*unity-webapps-gmail*) discontinued in 18.04

   Gmail Webapp for Unity
2. **Gmail Notify** (*gmail-notify*)

   Notify the arrival of new mail on Gmail
3. **Gnome Gmail** (*gnome-gmail*)

   GNOME Gmail integrates the Gmail web interface into the GNOME environment. Once installed, Gmail becomes a choice as the default Mail Reader in the GNOME Preferred Applications administration application. When selected, a Gmail webpage will be used whenever an email service is requested.
4. **CheckGMail** (*checkgmail*)

   CheckGmail is a system tray application that checks a Gmail account for new mail. When new mail is present the tray icon changes, an optional animated popup is displayed and a tooltip displays the number and details of new messages. Configuration is GUI-based and the application is designed to be simple, elegant and unobtrusive.
5. **Webmail for Linux Desktops** (*desktop-webmail*)

   Provides a generic mailto: handler and webmail config dialog that
   lets the user choose his preferred webmail provider on first run
   and through the desktops *Preferences*-> *Webmail* facility.
6. **Unity Mail** (*unity-mail*)

   Unity Mail is an application that integrates your mail into the Unity, MATE, Xfce, LXDE and other environments. It displays notifications about incoming mail, shows the number of unread messages and displays subjects in the Messaging Menu. The Launcher item also has a quicklist that provides quick access to your mail folders (configured for Gmail by default). It also allows you to quickly compose a new message.
7. **KGmailNotifier** (*kgmailnotifier*) discontinued in 18.04

   Gmail notifier applet for the KDE Plasma Workspace. When a new mail has arrived in your inbox a small window will pop up, showing author and subject of the newest mail. The underlined link will take you right to your inbox (using your preferred browser).

Answer (score 1):

If you have other mail client you in which you want to work with your mails, you can just simply go to System Settings -> Details -> Default Applications and change Thunderbird to a software of your choice.

[image: System settings]

[image: Default Applicatons]